# Visual Studio 2015 Angular JS default project produced 404 error for app.js

Tags: iis, typescript, visual-studio-2015

This is a bit of an embarrassing question but I'm unable to get the default Typescript project to work in VS2015. It seems to be an issue with the pc I'm using and not VS as the default project works on other machines at my work. When running a Typescript project from VS2015 I get a 404 error when loading in the app.js. From my understanding ISS should be converting app.ts into app.js. I tried removing the ISSExpress folder from documents and trying again and that didn't work. Has anyone got any suggestions to help me get typescript working without having to reinstall VS.

Thanks